# Geofencing with Javascript

Tags: javascript, geolocation

OK I'm trying to use one of the tried and true formulas to Geofence. My second alert in the code should be a result of true...yet it always says false. Any ideas?

```
var points = [{
    x: 35.586680,
    y: -80.874079
}, {
    x: 35.586646,
    y: -80.872840
}, {
    x: 35.585852,
    y: -80.872732
}, {
    x: 35.585673,
    y: -80.873918
}];


function isPointInPoly(poly, pt) {
    for (var c = false, i = -1, l = poly.length, j = l - 1; ++i < l; j = i)((poly[i].y <= pt.y && pt.y < poly[j].y) || (poly[j].y <= pt.y && pt.y < poly[i].y)) && (pt.x < (poly[j].x - poly[i].x) * (pt.y - poly[i].y) / (poly[j].y - poly[i].y) + poly[i].x) && (c = !c);
    return c;
}

jQuery(window).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#btnInit").click(initiate_geolocation);
    jQuery("#checkit").click(e);
});

function initiate_geolocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handle_geolocation_query);
}

function handle_geolocation_query(position) {
    alert('Lat: ' + position.coords.latitude + ' ' +
        'Lon: ' + position.coords.longitude);
    alert(isPointInPoly(points, {
        X: 35.586488,
        Y: -80.873660
    }));
    alert(isPointInPoly(points, {
        X: position.coords.latitude,
        y: position.coords.longitude
    }));
}
```

Here is the JSFiddle Link

http://jsfiddle.net/D2RL3/

Comment: It alerts true when `c` is changed to true, because you are saying `return c`

Answer (score 1):

You sent in 'wrong' object. You used capital `X` and `Y` instead of `x` and `y` for object properties:

```
alert(isPointInPoly(points, {
        X: 35.586488,
        Y: -80.873660
    }));
    alert(isPointInPoly(points, {
        X: position.coords.latitude,
        y: position.coords.longitude
    }));
```

JavaScript variable names are case sensitive. This code should be with small `x` and `y` object properties:

```
alert(isPointInPoly(points, {
        x: 35.586488,
        y: -80.873660
    }));
    alert(isPointInPoly(points, {
        x: position.coords.latitude,
        y: position.coords.longitude
    }));
```